# Light an led using raspberry pi remotely using web app hosted in hosts like hostgator

Tags: php, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

There are too many tutorials available about how to control led using raspberry pi using web app hosted in localhost,But how can I control the led using web app hosted in hosting services like hostgator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of the most basic ways to accomplish interacting with the RaspberryPi in this fashion would be to use web services.

**Internally Hosted Web Service**

Create a web service that runs on the RaspberryPi or another local system.  The external web application would then talk to this service.  This solution has the added difficulty that you will need a static IP or dynamic DNS so that your external web application knows where to contact your local service.

**Externally Hosted Web Service**

Create a web service that is hosted externally along with the web application.  The RaspberryPi then periodically polls the external web service for work, or long polls and waits for work to be pushed to it.

Comment: Can you please suggest a method to implement externally hosted web service?

Comment: @Sonu - That is an extremely broad question.  There are thousands of examples for creating webservices on the internet in every language imaginable.  Take some time to google for some examples in whatever language you would like and when you have specific problems feel free some come back to Stackoverflow and ask them.